# Additional Meta Data in Microsoft Word/Excel files

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Apart from the standard information stored in Word/Excel Meta Data (date created, revisions, author, etc) what additional information does/can it store.
For example, does it store system information by default (e.g. operating system, computer name etc) and if not, can it be added/read using VBA

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can store additional data e.g. in VBA code.
But what is our use case?

Comment: You asked this same question on June 6 2020 at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/45097-hidden-word-metadata-additional-data.html. Being so rude as to ask the same question without even acknowledging the advice you've already received elsewhere isn't going to change the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are interested in the [Document.BuiltInDocumentProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.builtindocumentproperties) property which returns a `DocumentProperties` collection that represents all the built-in document properties for the specified document. You can find the list of built-in properties in the [WdBuiltInProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdbuiltinproperty?view=word-pia) enum.

Also, you can add custom properties when dealing with the [Document.CustomDocumentProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.customdocumentproperties) property.